# Rich snippets not showing

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

We are faced with the problem of rich snippets not showing up in the search results on Google, for any recipes from our website.

Example: 
if you Googling this keyword "halep kebab sauce recipe" the first result you get is our website.

With the [rich snippet testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fglobalfoodbook.com%252Frecipe-items%252Fhalep-kebab%252F) all appears to work very well and without any errors.

Any idea why Google is not showing our rich snippets on their search pages?

Comment: I am not aware of recipes showing up in the SERPs. Do you have an example of one?? Not doubting you- it just may help us to know if this is knowledge-graph stuff.

Comment: trying googling "banana smoothie recipe" the fourth result has a recipe snippet

Comment: Unfortunately individual website troubleshooting is considered off-topic here, so unless you can provide more details or pinpoint the issue, users here could only guess. Also as you can see in the answer to the linked question: `Google does not guarantee that Rich Snippets will show up for search results from a particular site even if structured data is marked up`, and it can take quite a while for it to show up if it does.

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32917694/1591669